# Live Preview script using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".livepreview").livePreview({
    viewWidth: 400,
    viewHeight: 300,

  });

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#link").trigger("mouseenter");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.ampedupdesigns.com/js/jquery-live-preview.js"></script>

<a href="http://www.bing.com" target="_blank" id="link" class="livepreview">Hover over to preview, click to link!</a>
<br />
<button id="btn" class="clickpreview">Preview</button>
```

How can I make a live preview script using jQuery?

I want my users to be able to live preview a jQuery script so they can play around with the settings.

I found this script: [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/YARYp/3/show/light/) but it doesn't really reach my expectations for this.

So to explain it more: I want my users to preview their made changes to a script.